# JUnit code coverage for both try and catch blocks

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to write a JUnit for below code but I am not able to cover catch block in Junit code coverage and i am facing this issue since one week any suggestions for cover this block.

### Main class

```
@Autowired
ErrorHandler error;
try {

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            errorHandler.error(ErrorMessages.EPO_VALIDATEQ_ERROR_08, e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.EPO_SYSTEM_ERROR, e.getMessage(), url);
        }
```

### ErrorHandler

```
public void error(ResolvableErrorEnum error, String responseBody) {
        throw new ServiceException(error);
    }
```

### Junit

```
@Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void test_callUpdateCart_Exception() {
        AddToCartRequest req = createAddToCartRequest();

        String responseBodyStr = "{\"error\":{\"errorId\":\"Service-I-1003\",\"message\":\"Error returned from downstream system.\",\"traceCode\":\"CART;400\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"400\",\"message\":\"400 Bad Request\"},{\"code\":\"DTV_CAT_ERR_002\",\"message\":\"Error in getting response from catalog.\",\"traceCode\":\"CART;400\"}]}}\r\n";
        byte[] body = responseBodyStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        HttpClientErrorException e = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "BAD REQUEST", body,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        when(restTemplate.postForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>>any(), Mockito.eq(JsonNode.class)))
                .thenThrow(e);
        client.callUpdateCart(req);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You can try debugging. Possibly some code is throwing HttpServerErrorException before your mock code can run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock the `HttpClientErrorException` and use `doThrow()`

```
HttpClientErrorException exception = mock(HttpClientErrorException.class);
when(exception.getResponseBodyAsString()).thenReturn("BAD REQUEST");
doThrow(exception).when(restTemplate).postForObject(anyString(), any(), eq(JsonNode.class));
```

Comment: Could you put some code from the target test method

Comment: What do you mean of  target test method?I paste already EroorHandler classes where we are throwing error

Comment: I mean some code between try-catch because it should enter the HttpClientErrorException  case

Comment: I already pasted that Junit  code above and there i am throwing HttpClentError but code is not covering